# On the naming of two different median estimators

Tags: self-study, references, terminology, estimators, median

Assume that $X \sim \mathcal{E}(\lambda)$ is, for example, exponential with $\lambda > 0$. Given a data sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, assume that I want to estimate the median of $X$. Consider these two approaches:

1. Using the sample median as the estimate.
2. Estimating $\hat \lambda$ using maximum likelihood on the data sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, and plugging the ML estimate into the theoretical quantile function (e.g., on R, `qexp(0.5, rate = lambda_hat)`).

**My question**: how do I call/name these two approaches? I'm not sure how to formulate this question clearly, but do these two approaches have distinct names in the literature? Something along the lines of, 1: empirical median estimate; 2: parametric median estimate?

This question is maybe trivial, I'm looking into different statistics textbooks in non-english language and can't find the distinct names of these approaches besides the general section/chapter of the books. Would like to clear the naming conventions here in order to search for more relevant literature in english.

Comment: You can call them 1. nonparametric  2. parametric maximum likelihood estimator.  For the parametric estimate you are using a highly specific and restrictive parametric model. There are many methods that are halfway between the two once covariates are involved.

Comment: The first is an example of a "plug-in estimate."  The general idea is to estimate a property of the underlying distribution by means of the same property of the empirical distribution.  This is more specific than just being "nonparametric" (which covers a lot of ground).

Comment: If you are comparing only these two approaches, you could call them the naive and modeled estimators.